# Max length of extension cord for a 5kW load on 240?

Tags: cables

So we have a 5kW generator for our film set. We need to get it as far away from the set as possible. As well as leave the option for 25m consumer extension cord for lights and haze machines.

So what I need is to work out the max length I can get with a little voltage drop as possible.

We would not be using all 5kW on set, probably only around 4kW but I would like to leave some headroom.

Am I right in saying that 6 mm\$^2\$ pair with earth will be adequate for this?
I have Google'd this for a few days but not found a definite answer to this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "A 6mm pair with earth".

Comment: https://quickbit.co.uk/arctic-flex/Arctic-flex-blue-6mm-3-core-per-100m

Comment: ok, i'm pretty confident in saying that cable will be 6mm^2 CSA, not 6mm diameter. See the comments to Dave Tweed's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a resource like this page to find the resistance (ohms) per meter for wire of any particular diameter:
http://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-resistance-calculator.htm

By knowing the current (whatever you are powering?) and the total resistance of the wire (in both directions) then you can use Ohm's Law to calculate the voltage-drop you can expect.  I have a handy Ohm's Law calculator online here: http://www.rcrowley.com/eirp.htm

How much voltage-drop your loads can tollerate depends on what they are, how you are using them, and for how long. Remember that if you overload the extension cords, they will overheat and become dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

6mm<sup>2</sup> copper wire (slightly larger than AWG 10) has a resistance of about 2.8 mΩ/m, or 5.6 mΩ/m for the two wires in an extension cable.

5 kW would be about **21 A @ 240 V**. Let's say we can tolerate a 5% drop, or 12 V. This means we can have at most a total of 12 V / 21 A = 571 mΩ of resistance.

Therefore, the maximum distance with this cable would be 571 mΩ / 5.6 mΩ/m = 102 m.